# AspNetCore Cannot set cookie in Filter

Tags: asp.net-core, cookies

I have the following code that executes as a filter

```
    public async Task OnActionExecutionAsync(ActionExecutingContext context, ActionExecutionDelegate next)
    {
        {
            string empId = context.RouteData.Values[RouteValues.EmployerAccountId]?.ToString().ToUpper();

            const string StrictCookieKey = "strictCookie";
            const string LaxCookieKey = "laxCookie";

            string strictCookie = context.HttpContext.Request.Cookies[StrictCookieKey]?.ToString();
            string laxCookie = context.HttpContext.Request.Cookies[LaxCookieKey]?.ToString();

            context.HttpContext.Response.Cookies.Append(StrictCookieKey, "XXX", new CookieOptions
            {
                Secure = false,
                SameSite = SameSiteMode.Strict,
                HttpOnly = true
            });

            context.HttpContext.Response.Cookies.Append(LaxCookieKey, "XXX", new CookieOptions
            {
                Secure = false,
                SameSite = SameSiteMode.Lax,
                HttpOnly = true
            });

            context.Result = new RedirectResult(context.HttpContext.Request.Path);
            return;
        }
        // Some unreachable code here
```

The test is to see if I can write a cookie value and then redirect back to the same page and read it on the next request.

I am running this test on https://localhost:5020

What I see is that the lax cookie is sent again, but the strict cookie is not.

[image: Network tab]

The weirder thing is, if I don't close the browser when I stop the site - when I run the site it again it opens in the same browser in a new tab, and then the Strict cookie is set and retrieved correctly every time. Note, the value is set to the current time - and the value is updated on every request.

I can't work out what is causing this problem.

Comment: I could not reproduce your problem.I add the filter on action and it could get the strict cookie in next request.I do not understand  this code `context.Result = new RedirectResult(context.HttpContext.Request.Path);return;` and I use `await next()` to return to the action.

Comment: It's not calling next(), it's returning a direct to the same page.

Comment: If so,it will always redirect to the action and come into the filter again and again...

Comment: That is correct. This filter is an example of the problem - that setting cookies in a filter and redirecting isn't working on localhost unless I use Lax cookies.